# Can't build Docker image with detectron2 on MacOS

Tags: python, docker, macos, pip, detectron

Problem is that, I can't build image with `detectron2` using Docker. I use [official](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile) Dockerfile, that I found on GitHub:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.1.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04 # 18.04 didn't work also

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-opencv ca-certificates python3-dev git wget sudo ninja-build
RUN ln -sv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

ARG USER_ID=1000
RUN useradd -m --no-log-init --system  --uid ${USER_ID} appuser -g sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser

ENV PATH="/home/appuser/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3 get-pip.py --user && \
    rm get-pip.py

RUN pip install --user tensorboard cmake onnx   # cmake from apt-get is too old
RUN pip install --user torch==1.10 torchvision==0.11.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html

RUN pip install --user 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore'
RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2 detectron2_repo
ENV FORCE_CUDA="1"
ARG TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="Kepler;Kepler+Tesla;Maxwell;Maxwell+Tegra;Pascal;Volta;Turing"
ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="${TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST}"

RUN pip install --user -e detectron2_repo

ENV FVCORE_CACHE="/tmp"
WORKDIR /home/appuser/detectron2_repo

RUN pip install --user jupyterlab
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install Flask-RESTful
RUN pip install Werkzeug
```

I crushes from the like `RUN pip install --user -e detectron2_repo`. As a result I get just huge log but it ends with that:

```
#15 228.7     nvcc warning : The 'compute_35', 'compute_37', 'compute_50', 'sm_35', 'sm_37' and 'sm_50' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
#15 228.7     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
#15 228.7     Traceback (most recent call last):
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1717, in _run_ninja_build
#15 228.7         subprocess.run(
#15 228.7       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
#15 228.7         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
#15 228.7     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
#15 228.7
#15 228.7     The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#15 228.7
#15 228.7     Traceback (most recent call last):
#15 228.7       File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
#15 228.7       File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/detectron2_repo/setup.py", line 147, in <module>
#15 228.7         setup(
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
#15 228.7         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
#15 228.7         return run_commands(dist)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
#15 228.7         dist.run_commands()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
#15 228.7         self.run_command(cmd)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
#15 228.7         super().run_command(command)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
#15 228.7         cmd_obj.run()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 34, in run
#15 228.7         self.install_for_development()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 114, in install_for_development
#15 228.7         self.run_command('build_ext')
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
#15 228.7         self.distribution.run_command(command)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1208, in run_command
#15 228.7         super().run_command(command)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
#15 228.7         cmd_obj.run()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
#15 228.7         _build_ext.run(self)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
#15 228.7         self.build_extensions()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 735, in build_extensions
#15 228.7         build_ext.build_extensions(self)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 468, in build_extensions
#15 228.7         self._build_extensions_serial()
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 494, in _build_extensions_serial
#15 228.7         self.build_extension(ext)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
#15 228.7         _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 549, in build_extension
#15 228.7         objects = self.compiler.compile(
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 556, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
#15 228.7         _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1399, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
#15 228.7         _run_ninja_build(
#15 228.7       File "/home/appuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1733, in _run_ninja_build
#15 228.7         raise RuntimeError(message) from e
#15 228.7     RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
#15 228.7     [end of output]
#15 228.7
#15 228.7 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --user -e detectron2_repo]: exit code: 1
```

I guess it is something about `cuda`, but I am not really sure, because docker works in the isolated environment.

Here is the configuration of my computer:

- MacBook Pro
- 2,4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB
- 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3

Comment: You need to include the whole error message, not the last line, as it effectively does not say anything.

Answer (score 0):

This dockerfile expects you to have a CUDA enabled graphics card from nvidia. Your macbook does not have this kind of graphics card.